# Website renders differently on server vs locally

Tags: linux, web, local, html-rendering

I'm having a very bizarre issue. I have been building a website locally on my linux box and all was well until I uploaded the site files to a place where i have some hosted space. Everything renders exactly the same except one element in my footer which i think is affecting some jquery animation i am using. I thought maybe I was missing files or hadn't uploaded the latest versions of everything, so I deleted the server directory and re-uploaded everything exactly as is from my local copy. And yet, the problem remains. I'm not sure how this is happening. Has anyone seen this before, or does anyone have an idea what could cause this? I'm baffled! Thanks everyone!!! I am attaching screen shots. 
[image: the local copy with correct footer]

[image: the server version with footer that overflows]

Comment: Interesting... from comparing the screenshots, the word "News" is exactly one pixel wider in the server version (gap between w and s), but the font size is identical. I have no idea what causes this, but adding a few extra pixels to your `#bottom h3`'s width won't hurt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be a cache problem. Try to force a refresh with F5 or CTRL+F5.

Try clear your cache in your browser settings.

If that don't work, use Firebug (an Firefox browser addon) to check actual css at your footer. This will show the problem.

BTW: don't use spaces in your URL if you can. Don't use spaces in your filenames/folders.

Comment: that solved that problem! thanks! sorry for the delayed gratitude :(